# HDD mounting screws size

Tags: hard-drive

I recently bought a WD Green HDD (WD30EZRX) and it came without any screws. What size screws do I need for it? The screw size is not listed in the product specification on the manufacturer's website as far as I can find and I couldn't find anything via google either. The standard computer screws are too thick for the holes.

Comment: no, I doublechecked just now, I have both those types of standard screws and they are too thick for the holes

Comment: They are a standard -- if the holes are wrong, then the drive is manufactured wrong.  More likely, you have the wrong screws in hand.

Comment: the screws I have include the screws that used to be in the old HDD so those aren't wrong at least. Are you sure there isn't some third type of 'standard' screw? The holes are about half the width of the ones in the old HDD.

Comment: Nope, HDD screw holes are standardized, else they wouldn't fit into the plethora of standard chassis and drive carriers that exist already. If you are SURE you've got the right screws in hand, then the drive has a manufacturing defect.  Can you supply us a picture of your drive's screw holes and the screws you're trying to use?

Answer (score 5):

this is wat you need to add <s>5,25"</s> 3.5"(desktop) hd's

## 6-32 x 1/4"

http://www.microcenter.com/product/218378/6-32_Computer_Case_Screws_15_Pack

ok for a 2.5" you need
for 2.5"
M3 x 4mm

**Added by barlop**

according to http://www.laptopscrews.com/HDD.htm   "The hard drive in a laptop will always take an M3 diameter screw. This is an industry standard and is true of all brands."  (and it makes the point that some mistakenly say M2.5).

As for length.  I just tried 4mm in a dell vostro 1710, and it was too long and the head was too thick.  Perhaps 2mm is the right length and specifically a thin head.. It may be a good idea to get a screw set on ebay..or see if a repair shop will assist as they'll likely have a box of screws though they might look at it as a fix albeit a cheap one like the cost of "looking at" the laptop when bringing it in to show them.

Comment: 5.25" HDDs? What decade are you living in? :)

Comment: oeps looked liked an old drive :) so for 2.5 you need M3 x 4mm

Comment: 5.25" is the size of an optical drive (larger bays).  The "regular" desktop HDD size since about the 90's is 3.5", laptop drives are 2.5".  New SSDs are also 2.5" (for the most part), and they almost all come with a 3.5" adapter. ;)  [Full height 5.25" HDD vs. 2.5" HDD](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/5.25_inch_MFM_hard_disk_drive.JPG)

Comment: And your link is broken and  wouldn't have covered laptop hdd screws, and you have provided no reference regarding laptop hdd screw size.

Comment: And in the case of the laptop I just saw, you're wrong re 4mm and you haven't specified the width of the head which can be an issue too.

Comment: "industry standard" nope, they vary between M1-4 in my experience, and newer devices if they use them at all may have randomly sized torx! Probably true on some saying M2.5 though...